# What are the events that may help identify when an azure app service is down?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

We have an app service that needs to be monitored and notify a set of users when it is down.

Right now, I am just using Activity Log's Service Stopped to check for it.
What more conditions can be added to make it work in many scenarios as possible?

Thank You

Comment: Use any of the available metrics that suites your need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for raising a question and contributing to Stack Overflow.

- As Daniel has mentioned you could use Azure Monitor and Application Insights.
- Application Insights would also be a better approach, since it helps collect telemetry from your application to analyze its operation and performance.
- You can use this information to identify problems that may be occurring or to identify improvements to the application that would most impact users.

Also you can go through the below doc for more reference : [App Service Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net)